# The elements inside the MaterialCardView are not clipped at the edges

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to make a MaterialCardView with different rounds.

Everything is fine on the layout in Android Studio. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nst2Q.png)

But when I run it on android, there are no more rounds. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1gya.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        app:cardElevation="15dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/CustomShapeAppearance">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_second"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/filledTextField"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="@string/InsertLogin">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/username_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/InsertPassWord"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="#00FFFFFF">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
                        style="@style/AppTheme"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_main"
                android:text="@string/Login"
                app:backgroundTint="@null" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</FrameLayout>
```

I tried to make my own class, but it doesn't work as it should. If one of the corners is different from all, then the rounding is not visible again.

```
public class MyMaterialCardView extends MaterialCardView {
    private float radiusTopLeft = 20;
    private float radiusTopRight = 20;
    private float radiusBottomRight = 20;
    private float radiusBottomLeft = 20;

    public MyMaterialCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public MyMaterialCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public MyMaterialCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyMaterialCardView);
            radiusTopLeft = a.getDimension(R.styleable.MyMaterialCardView_radiusTopLeft, 20);
            radiusTopRight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.MyMaterialCardView_radiusTopRight, 20);
            radiusBottomRight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.MyMaterialCardView_radiusBottomRight, 20);
            radiusBottomLeft = a.getDimension(R.styleable.MyMaterialCardView_radiusBottomLeft, 20);
            a.recycle();
        }
        ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radiusTopLeft)
                .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radiusTopRight)
                .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radiusBottomRight)
                .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radiusBottomLeft)
                .build();


        setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Android are you running it on?

Comment: @karllindmark Android 12

Answer (score 0):

I`m do THIS!

```html
public class RoundedCornerLayout extends MyMaterialCardView {

    private Path path = new Path();
    private RectF rect = new RectF();
    private float[] cornerRadii = new float[8];

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedCornerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedCornerLayout);


            float radiusTopLeft = a.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedCornerLayout_cornerRadiusTopLeft, 0);
            float radiusTopRight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedCornerLayout_cornerRadiusTopRight, 0);
            float radiusBottomRight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedCornerLayout_cornerRadiusBottomRight, 0);
            float radiusBottomLeft = a.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedCornerLayout_cornerRadiusBottomLeft, 0);

            cornerRadii[0] = cornerRadii[1] =radiusTopLeft;
            cornerRadii[2] = cornerRadii[3] =radiusTopRight;
            cornerRadii[4] = cornerRadii[5] =radiusBottomRight;
            cornerRadii[6] = cornerRadii[7] =radiusBottomLeft;
            a.recycle();


            ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = getShapeAppearanceModel()
                    .toBuilder()
                    .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radiusTopLeft)
                    .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radiusTopRight)
                    .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radiusBottomRight)
                    .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radiusBottomLeft)
                    .build();


            setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModel);


        }
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,int heightMeasureSpec){
        int count=getChildCount();
        int maxHeight=0;
        int maxWidth=0;

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            final View child=getChildAt(i);
            if(child.getVisibility()!=GONE){
                measureChild(child,widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
                maxWidth=Math.max(maxWidth,
                        child.getMeasuredWidth());
                maxHeight=Math.max(maxHeight,
                        child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }

        maxWidth+=getPaddingLeft()+getPaddingRight();
        maxHeight+=getPaddingTop()+getPaddingBottom();

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSizeAndState(maxWidth,widthMeasureSpec , 0),
                resolveSizeAndState(maxHeight,heightMeasureSpec , 0));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed,int l,int t,int r,int b){
        int count=getChildCount();

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            final View child=getChildAt(i);
            if(child.getVisibility()!=GONE){
                child.layout(getPaddingLeft(),getPaddingTop(),
                        getPaddingLeft()+child.getMeasuredWidth(),
                        getPaddingTop()+child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        rect.set(0f , 0f , getWidth() , getHeight());

        path.addRoundRect(rect,
                cornerRadii,
                Path.Direction.CW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);

        super.draw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```